# My ubuntu terminal is opening as "gdhobe@vfroot-Thinkpad-T440:~$" I want to open it as "vfroot-Thinkpad-T440:~$"

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

My ubuntu terminal is opening as "gdhobe@vfroot-Thinkpad-T440:~$" I want to open it as "vfroot-Thinkpad-T440:~$"

Usually terminal opens as vfroot-Thinkpad-T440:~$

How this issue could be solved.

Comment: Issue solved with "su username"

Comment: `\u` in `PS1` is the username, so set a `PS1` without it, or edit your current `PS1` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal do:

```
printf '\nPS1="\h:\w$"\n' >> ~/.bashrc
```

then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and it's done. Note that this solution is very simple one - this doesn't include colorizing the prompt.